# Error when installing opencv (any version) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, compiling, ffmpeg, cmake, opencv

I got an error in `make` command in opencv.

```
[/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:446: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8437: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[image]

Comment: The line ending with "; recompile with -fPIC" is essential info as far as I can see. I believe you have to verify that you're doing something sane with the code you're compiling. Generally it is a lot easier to find a ppa or even a *.deb -file and install that instead.

Comment: Opencv compiles against ffmpeg (if you didn't turn that off). Looks like you need the ffmpeg headers. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) for more infos

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the libavcodec (directly installed on your system or in-directly installed via FFmpeg) library present on your system is not built as a "shared library". And OpenCV by [default](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html#tutorial_config_reference_general_static) has a cmake (configuration) option **BUILD_SHARED_LIBS** as *ON* on most platforms and on Ubuntu 18.04, its ***ON***. You have at least 3 options to deal with this:

- Configure and Build OpenCV as static by setting OpenCV's cmake configuration **BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF** before executing make as follows:

  ```
    cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ../opencv && make
  ```
- Configure and Build OpenCV without FFmpeg (*ON* is the [default](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html#tutorial_config_reference_func_videoio) build option on most platforms including Ubuntu 18.04) by setting OpenCV's cmake configuration **WITH_FFMPEG=OFF** before executing make as follows:

  ```
    cmake -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF ../opencv && make
  ```
- Build libavcodec as a "shared library". However, libavcodec is a part of FFmpeg and I know only how to build it along with FFmpeg. You can try searching for ways to build libavcodec alone as a shared library without building all the extras that come with FFmpeg, though I am not sure if OpenCV needs the rest of FFmpeg anyway as I only tried building the entire FFmpeg package along with OpenCV. Anyone who knows better, feel free to edit this answer. Since FFmpeg is very often built with other libraries, I am including steps to build libx264 also as a shared library as an example.. other libraries will probably have similar configuration steps to build it as a shared library. You may ignore the first line of command as well as the `--enable-libx264` option in FFmpeg config if you don't need x264 encode support in FFmpeg. Here I am gonna install the X264 and FFmpeg libraries system wide but you may want to install to a local folder instead:

  ```
    git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264.git && cd x264 && git checkout remotes/origin/stable && ./configure --enable-shared && make -j12 && sudo make install-lib-shared -j12 && cd ../;
    git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git && cd FFmpeg && git checkout remotes/origin/release/4.3 && ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-shared && make -j12 && sudo make install -j12 && cd ../;
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && cd opencv && git checkout 1363496 && mkdir build && cd build && mkdir install && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ../ && cmake --build . --target install -- -j12 ;
  ```

In the commands above `../opencv` is the path of the root directory of OpenCV source code and the command is being executed inside a temporary build directory. For more guidance refer [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d65/tutorial_table_of_content_introduction.html). Also, I have checked out the most recent stable release version for each package as on the original date of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you have enabled the use of inline assembler, and if you want to use a static build of `ffmpeg`s libraries, you have to use

```
-Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

when linking your own shared library. You can search online to find why, the explanation won't fit in an answer.